# android stop thread

Tags: android, multithreading, arrays, nullpointerexception

hi im wanting to stop all threads when my main activity closes as some are still running afterwards and are giving NullPointerException as they try to access ArrayLists which no longer exist. however none of the obvious methods are working and they are also deprecated. is it possible as im currently using a try/catch statement as a workaround but would prefer a fix.

TIA

ng93

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your MainActivity tell your threads that it's time to end. You could do this with some sort of value that each thread checks before they access the ArrayLists. Or you could live with the try/catch workaround. But there aren't any good, safe ways of killing threads, which is why those methods got deprecated.

Comment: damn was worried that might be the case. I'll be sticking with the try/catch then. cheers